# How to disable breadcrumbs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, breadcrumbs

How can I disable the Java editor breadcrumb in Eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 511, accepted):

If you are referring to the breadcrumbs in the help file of a RCP application, there is <del>only</del>  a [manual way to do it](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg68472.html).

Since [Ganymede 3.4M5](http://giano.com.dist.unige.it/eclipseMirror/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.4M5-200802071530/eclipse-news-M5.html):

[image: Initial Breadcrump GUI]

- [Michael Borgwardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16883/michael-borgwardt) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069794/6309) the toolbar icon [image: dd]
- [Slava Semushin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352708/slava-semushin) [provides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9869403/6309) a native shortcut based on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>+`bread`, which points directly to the `Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb` option.
- [Shachi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2034700/shachi) reminds us [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15154516/6309) that you can right-click on any icon on the breadcrumb, and select the entry named "`Hide Breadcrumb`".

[image: Hide breadcrumbs]

---

Original answer (manual way, through key mapping)

> Find the file `org.eclipse.help.webapp\advanced\breadcrumbs.css` and replace its contents with.

```
.help_breadcrumbs {
   display: none;
}
```

---

For the Java Editor breadcrumb, you need to assign a shortcut to the "Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb" command (I have tested <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, for instance)

[image]

That shortcut will make the breadcrumb bar appear/disappear at will.

Comment: For some reason I didn't have the toolbar item, even though I had Java Editor Presentation checked. The key stroke worked.

Comment: Creating a shortcut is not necessary.  The best answer is the one by Michael Borgwardt but also the one by Slava Semushin is very interesting.

Comment: more than 70000 views and 400 upvotes - this looks like a serious useability issue in Eclipse.

Answer (score 173):

With the editor window focussed, look for this icon in your toolbar: [image: button to click]

And click on it. That's all. The icon is present by default, but can be deactivated, in which case you have to activated as in MvanGeest's answer.

Comment: Or via keyboard with command+option+b on the Mac (and I suppose ctrl+alt+b on others).

Comment: Handily the accepted answer's length necessitates scrolling this one into view =)

Comment: Just another thank you. Seriously, I've forgotten where the darn button is and wound up back here half a dozen times.

Answer (score 63):

Another way which works for me at Eclipse Indigo (3.7): press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and type `bread`, after that click on item `Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb`.

Answer (score 62):

1. **RightClick** on any icon on breadcrumb.
2. There is an option named **HIDE BREADCRUMB**.
3. **Click it** and you are **done**. :D

Answer (score 26):

Look for this icon in the toolbar:
[image: button to click]

This button toggles the Breadcrumb view on/off.

(I'm using Eclipse 3.7, and it's there by default)

Answer (score 18):

Here it is : [image]

[image]

In the toolbar, toggle bread crumb option.

Answer (score 6):

Something like http://loadcontext.blogspot.com/2008/08/eclipse-34-breadcrumbs-hide-and-show.html?

> Customize Perspective, choose the
>   Commands tab. In the Available command
>   group, choose Java Editor
>   Presentation. The Toolbar details
>   shows the button for Toggle
>   Breadcrumbs, which looks like a folder
>   with a C in a circle with a black
>   triangle on top of it.

Despite my absolute lack of experience with Eclipse, I suppose this setting must appear in other Presentation items too. After the button's enabled, all you have to do is click it. Or not?

Answer (score 3):

Change property `breadcrumb.org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective` from `true` to `false`
in your `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` file.

Answer (score 1):

In Juno: type 'Bread' and select 'Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb'

Comment: Is Juno and Eclipse the same thing?

Comment: Juno is version 4.2 (currently the newest) of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It very simple just right click in your class editor then select bread crumb or directly right click in top of your class in tool bar then select hide breadcrumb  then its done.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the BreadCrumb toolbar, right-click on the green class icon and then from the menu options click on Hide Breadcrumb.