# remove a view from eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have been messing around with eclipse and i got this view, that i can't now remove.

[image]

any ideas?

it seems that it shows me the path in the editor area, but i don't want it to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its breadcrumb. To hide it again click on button shown in following image in red box:
[image]

[image]

Comment: @aman: if it helps then you should upvote or accept it so that others know that its correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this?
[How to disable breadcrumbs in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069589/how-to-disable-breadcrumbs-in-eclipse)