# eclipse java editor view

Tags: eclipse

I pressed right mouse button and accidentally selected SOMETHING which I cannot revert anymore. Now I have a small panel on top of my editor which shows a very detailed project layout (begins with project name and goes down till method declarations). I don't want that there. How do I remove it?[image]

Please help! Thank you!

Edit: the panel seems to represent the type hierarchy of my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable breadcrumbs in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069589/how-to-disable-breadcrumbs-in-eclipse)

Comment: thank you, this link solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very simple.. 'Undo ' the breadcrumb option[image: breadcrum_undo]