# How do I get rid of this unwanted bar from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, breadcrumbs

When coding in Eclipse(Indigo), I accidentally hit a combination of keys which made this bar appear when I was doing some shortcuts. This question has probably being answered before but since I don't know the exact name of the bar googling the problem has being fruitless. I've spent two hours trying to fix it. So anyone know how to get rid of this bar in the image below?

[image: Problem]

Comment: Your question saved me a few minutes by coming up as the result of my desperate query on google. Hence, it must not be stupid! qed

Comment: Thanks! Google's nicely optimised for indexing 'stupid' questions so this helped me out too :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650664/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-unwanted-bar-from-eclipse

Comment: Simple 2 step solution. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15154516/1999190) is my answer to similiar SO question.

Comment: And for bonus points, what was that accidental combination of keys? I hit them too ...

Answer (score 241, accepted):

The bar you are talking about is the *breadcrumbs*.

To remove it, look at your toolbar which should more or less look like this:
[image]

Then, click that button that is on the very far right.  It looks like a little C with a green circle, a black triangle, and some small blue thing in the back.  Find that button on your eclipse toolbar and click it to show/hide breadcrumbs.

If you don't see it, let me know, and I can try to figure out which toolbar it is a part of.

Comment: Thank you, I feel quite stupid! I didn't hover over that icon as it looked like it was related to a class. Doh!

Comment: What a crap UI.

Comment: really crap UI. i second that. they should have put a cross icon right there.

Comment: Thanks, just a note that it may not be on the far right of the toolbar ribbon, just depends on how you've set it up.  +1 for a crap UI idea.

Answer (score 38):

Using the Scala View, I neither had the icon mentioned in the accepted answer nor did Alt+Shift+B work.

What did work for me: Right click in the unwanted breadcrumb bar and click *Hide Breadcrumb*.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as well!  The button wasn't there for me.

Comment: The right click has to be on the text within the breadcrumb bar.  Clicking on the empty space on the breadcrumb bar had no effect, but the text (filename in my case) brought up a large menu among which one of the choices was, Hide Breadcrumb.

Answer (score 19):

When you right-click the breadcrumb bar, you need to right-click one of the words. Just clicking the bar does not work

Answer (score 11):

right click on the breadcrum and click hide beadcrumb option.

Answer (score 2):

just click the [button next new class button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQSBM.png) and problem solved. And If you want breadcrumb just hit alt+shift+B. hit the link for image

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the other answers, the "toggle breadcrumb" button may be in an alternate location on the toolbar as in this image:

[image: Alternate toolbar]