# How can I hide this annoying toolbar

Tags: eclipse

I clicked by mistake on something in eclipse, and annoying toolbar apeared. how can I hide it?
[image]

I know it is stupid question but I couldnt find answer on the internet.

Comment: I think this has been answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069589/how-to-disable-breadcrumbs-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press Ctrl+3 and type bread, after that click on item Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb.