# How to close this navigation menu on the editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, view

How can I close this navigation menu on Eclipse?
[image]

Please help me. It is annoying and bad for my OCD.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the `Toggle Breadcrumb` button in the toolbar. It's the one in the middle which is currently active.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is called the breadcumb bar, so you can toggle it with `Ctrl+3 > Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb` or [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069751/90874).