# Eclipse add type hierarchy to under opened files

Tags: eclipse

I have two laptops and on one of them in Eclipse I was able to add a type hierarchy that shows class members, etc. directly under the opened files (or whatever you call the tabs that are right about the red box in my image). I have no idea how to do this though, anyone have any suggestions?

Also, on a related note, when I do just open the type hierarchy it always requires that I open it given the context of the current opened .java file. On my other laptop it's sort of dynamic and allows me to explore the type hierarchy of whatever file I'm viewing. I want it all to work like how it is in Microsoft Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069589/how-to-disable-breadcrumbs-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the `breadcrumb` - `Navigate > Show in Breadcrumb`