# Turn off eclipse code navigation toolbar

Tags: eclipse, navigation, toolbar, breadcrumbs

I accidentally clicked something, which made this appear:

[image: Navigation toolbar]

Now I don't know how to turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing called breadcrumbs.

Please take a look to this post [How to disable breadcrumbs in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069589/how-to-disable-breadcrumbs-in-eclipse) to disable it