# Eclipse Bar Above Code

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anyone have a clue how to remove the bar which I circled in red in Eclipse? I have the package explorer view open at the left side and I think it is more than sufficient.

[image: Eclipse]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Sure - that's the *breadcrumb* view.

You can toggle it on or off with this button:

[image: Breadcrumb button]

(I'm struggling to find a *menu* option to toggle it at the moment, but I'm sure there's one somewhere.)

Alternatively, you can hide it in the context menu for the breadcrumb itself.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that it was called the breadcrumb view (sorry if it was a duplicate question).

Answer (score 1):

This option is known as breadcrumb view.

You can toggle it with shortcut

**Alt + Shift + B**

([look is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069589/how-to-disable-breadcrumbs-in-eclipse)). Note that this shortcut is not functional on all eclipse version.

You can enable / disable breadcrumb view in Preferenes > General > Keys - Option Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb and there you can set your own shortcut.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]