# Cannot hide some toolbar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Somehow I accidentally enabled some toolbar just above the code and below the tabs which shows me project and packages that the currently opened file (java file) belongs to. Has anyone got an idea how to turn it off because it's driving me crazy... The eclipse version is Kepler. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: This is the Breadcrumb - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3069589/2670892

Comment: Thank you sir! Unfortunately I cannot accept your comment so if you want make it an answer!

Comment: This is a duplicate so there is no need for an answer.