# How to remove Eclipse explore toolbar?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I remove the toolbar from the [image: screenshot]? (Elipse Mars or Neon)

Edit: In the meantime I've learned this is called the "breadcrumb" and available only for Java editors.

Comment: This is the breadcrumb view see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3069589/2670892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Quick Access* (**Ctrl+3**) enter "**Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb**" and hit Enter.

Or:
In your toolbar, you've got an icon called "Toggle Breadcrumb" (see image below). Just click on it to remove what you call "the explore toolbar".

[image]

By the way, I see you have hidden you main toolbar. Just in case you are wondering, to make it appear again (and the Toggle Breadcrumb icon), go to Window -> Appearance -> Show Toolbar.

Also, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to the Breadcrumb option. Go to Window -> General -> Keys, and search for "breadcrumb" in the search bar. The option is called "Toggle Java Editor Breadcrumb" in Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I had hidden the main toolbar on purpose, I'm trying to get some screen real-estate!