# What is this white-bar in the Eclipse Oxygen IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have had this white bar appear on my latest Eclipse installations (right under all open classes). It's very annoying and I have not found out what makes it appear.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It appears to be issue with theme you are using

Answer (score 3):

It's called the "Breadcrumb Bar", and it looks like it it not properly styled/supported by the theme you are using.

If you want to remove the bar, [here's a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069751/5117236).

Comment: Thanks! Prior to this I did not even know what breadcrumb bar was :)